# Any way to move constexpr function that returns std::optional inside struct where it is used?

Tags: c++, constexpr, stdoptional

I understand that the title of the question is confusing, so here is the example:

```
#include<array>
#include<optional>
#include<type_traits>

static constexpr std::optional<int> maybe_int() {
    return  {64};
}
struct s {

    using type = std::conditional_t< maybe_int().has_value(), std::array<int, *maybe_int()>,float > ;
};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<s::type, std::array<int,64>>);
```

This code compiles fine but when I move `maybe_int` inside struct compilation fails.

> error: 'static constexpr std::optional<int> s::maybe_int()' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete

Note that I know the code works fine with free function, this is about readability. So I would like to move `maybe_int` inside struct s.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? [GCC compiles as-is](https://godbolt.org/g/s8EjHq).

Comment: @Xirema like I said : when I move maybe_int inside struct compilation fails

Comment: @Xirema Are you being serious? Is is *that* hard to move the function *exactly* the way the OP specified?

Comment: @Xirema the question stated "This code compiles fine."  [This is the code that causes the failure](https://godbolt.org/g/sBdhGT).

Comment: You won't be able to due to the reason in the answer on the duplicate.  You could put the code in a namespace so as to not pollute the global space.

Comment: @Rakete1111 FWIW, there's [an open issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1626) suggesting that the template case should be handled the same as the non-template case, at which point your suggestion would stop working.

Comment: @hvd Ha, I knew this was hack :) Thanks for mentioning this, I didn't know.